# How do I make a button on a form behave like a button on a toolStrip? VS2008

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, button, toolstrip

How do I make a button on a form behave like a button on a toolStrip?

I want a menu-type list to come down. I tried using a toolStripContainer but it is very hard to manipulate to get it to behave as just one button.

Is there an easier way than just putting a toolStrip with one button in a toolStripContainer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the ToolStripContainer, just use a ToolStrip (with 1 button).

set

```
toolStrip1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
toolStrip1.AutoSize = true
```